# Is there a way to include adobe air in a packaged android app built with Flash Builder 4.5?

Tags: android, air, adobe, flash-builder

I'm considering switching to developing on Flash Builder 4.5 since apps can be built for most platforms.  So would it be possible to include Adobe AIR with the app or somehow have it hardcoded into the app to automatically download Adobe AIR if they don't already have it **without prompting the user**?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You do know that Adobe discontinued development of Flash on Mobile.

E.g. read

http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/nov/09/adobe-flash-mobile-dead

http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/11/adobe-kills-mobile-flash/

http://www.engadget.com/2011/11/09/adobe-confirms-flash-player-is-dead-for-mobile-devices/

Adobe does not say this officially but without a mobile game for Flash they basically admit that Flash is dead and HTML 5 is the future. If they don't bank on it, nor should you.

**Update:** It seems that Air is still being developed by Adobe to run on mobile devices and is not dead. It might be a suitable platform for mobile app development but I am not qualified to judge on that. Personally I lean towards truly native apps but depending on your business case for a specific apps other approaches might be suitable.

Comment: Really?  I didn't know that.  So essentially future generations of devices will no longer support this?  Is there an article somewhere?

Comment: Interesting.  Well, I suppose developing separately with java for android and obj c for iOS would be the best route then, right?  I mean, even if I do decide to continue with Flash Builder to develop said apps, then support would be lost AND I'd still have to tell the user to download Adobe AIR, if their device even supports it anymore...

Comment: There are other cross platform mobile options like PhoneGap but imho its either native app or good mobile website.

Comment: Flash and AIR are two different things, AIR will be developed way farther. Do not post things you are not sure about, person above clearly stated AIR. http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/06/flash-player-and-android-update.html You can include the runtime installer with your application, but it still will ask the user to install runtime before it installs the app.

Comment: Afaik the Adobe AIR uses the Adobe Flash Player runtime internally and as such if Adobe Flash for Mobile is dead, so is AIR in the long run. Time only will tell of course.

Comment: Flash and AIR are two different thing. Flash is dead. AIR is not.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can include runtime with your app just like you would do it for IOS.

When compiling for AIR 3.x compile using following switch:

```
adt -package -target ( apk | apk-debug | apk-emulator | apk-captive-runtime )
```

`apk-captive-runtime` will include the runtime with your APK. Tested and working.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe did not discontinue development of air on mobile. But on mobile web browsers and linux.
So far if you want to develop an application with adobe air on iphone or android it's possible, for android you will have to check for some hardware restrictions though.

If you check on the links posted previously you'll see that it's just for browsers.

Whatever the solution you will take to try to be cross platform there will always be some issues. I have chosen adobe air because Adobe is a reliable company and making apps with air is super fast.

Comment: this might be outdated